# Navigation Tabs, Adding the Active Class

Tags: jquery, button

I have written some horrible jQuery code (as I am new to JS). I have four buttons, when i click one it will add the active class which changes the background colour on the tab i have just clicked. It works but I know there is a better way to do it, my code is like 30 lines long and i know using the 'this' feature it can be done in like 4. Could someone show me how please:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#privacyTitle').click(function(e) {

        $('#SecurityTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#wisemanTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#manualTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#privacyTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SecurityTitle').click(function(e) {

        $('#privacyTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#wisemanTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#manualTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#SecurityTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#wisemanTitle').click(function(e) {

        $('#privacyTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#SecurityTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#manualTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#wisemanTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#manualTitle').click(function(e) {

        $('#privacyTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#wisemanTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#SecurityTitle').removeClass('active');
        $('#manualTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

<div class="row" id="content">
   <div class="tab">
      <button id="privacyTitle" class="tablinks">Privacy by Design</button><button class="tablinks" id="SecurityTitle">Security Design Assurance</button><button class="tablinks" id="wisemanTitle">Wiseman</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="manualTitle">Manual Risk Assessment</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) for your case. Something like below can help, (it's not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#privacyTitle').click(function(e) {
        $(".tablinks").removeClass('active');
        $('#privacyTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#SecurityTitle').click(function(e) {
        $(".tablinks").removeClass('active');
        $('#SecurityTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#wisemanTitle').click(function(e) {
        $(".tablinks").removeClass('active');
        $('#wisemanTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#manualTitle').click(function(e) {
        $(".tablinks").removeClass('active');
        $('#manualTitle').addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this concept and modify to meet your setup, I've used vanilla but you could transform to jQuery if you really need

```
document.querySelector('.tab').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //remove other tabs
    tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks')
    if(tabs !== null){
      tabs.forEach(function(tab){
        tab.classList.remove('active');
      })
    }

    // add active to clicked
    var tab = e.target;
    tab.classList.add('active');
})
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/duhixabuqo/edit?html,css,js,output)